# ¿Cómo eliminar un proyecto realizado en React de manera Local?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm

Hola recientemente termine un proyecto hecho con NodeJS, ReactJS, Flask y MySQL, esta alojado en un repositorio en GitHub, por lo tanto, ya no debería preocuparme si elimino el proyecto. Quiero liberar espacio en mi disco duro, pero no basta con simplemente eliminar la carpeta del proyecto, demora mucho y no creo que sea la forma correcta.

He visto que con el comando:
`npx npkill`

No sé si sea el comando adecuado para este caso, solo quiero **deshacerme del proyecto, no de NodeJS**. Podrían orientarme, se los agradecería mucho, buen día! :)

Comment: *pero no basta con simplemente eliminar la carpeta del proyecto* -> Y por qué no basta?? Si instalaste los módulos que hayas usado de manera correcta en la carpeta del proyecto y no en otra parte de tu pc, eliminando la carpeta del proyecto eliminarás absolutamente todo... Tarda mucho? Claro que si, bienvenido al maravilloso mundo del *node_modules*, la carpeta que contiene el universo entero (o casi). Tiene miles de archivos pequeños, lo cual es bastante lento de ir eliminando (a tu pc le gusta eliminar cosas grandes, no muchas cosas pequeñas)

Comment: Si todo esta en orden en ese proyecto, la cosa es que node_modules es enorme y si tarda mucho como dices, lo había intentado antes pero se requiere mucho tiempo. Solo que imagine que había una manera mas rápida de borrarlo jajaja